# Learning clisp regexp

Tags: common-lisp, clisp

Trying to do my first steps in lisp:

I'm finding the following behaviour that, AFAIK, is incorrect.

```
[185]> (if (regexp:match "[:alnum:]" "2" :extended t) t nil)
NIL
[186]> (if (regexp:match "[:alnum:0-9]" "2" :extended t) t nil)
T
```

I understand :alnum: should include digits, but, apparently it doesn't!

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The engine probably doesn't support `[:alnum:]`. You could use `[A-Za-z0-9_]` instead. `\w` might also work (at least if you switch to [cl-ppcre](http://weitz.de/cl-ppcre/)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax for character classes is "[:alnum:]", *including* the square brackets. So if you want to match, you have to write it like this:

```
(regexp:match "[[:alnum:]]" "2" :extended t)
```